# Google Map Error

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm getting an error with my google map script. Obviously I've messed up something to do with setting it to true or false?

http://cornerstonemedical.ie/contact.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the  line You have `...&sensor=true_or_false`.
Set it to `...&sensor=true` or `...&sensor=false`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=set_to_true_or_false
```

As the alert already says, you need either

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true
```

or

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
```

I hope you are following the [tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html), and you should have come across this sentence:

> Note that we also need to set a `sensor` parameter to indicate whether this application uses a sensor to determine the user's location. We've left this example as a variable *`set_to_true_or_false`* to emphasize that you **must** set this value to either `true` or `false` explicitly.

Comment: That would make sense.....sorry man, I'm as simple as they come! I was trying: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor: true

Answer (score 0):

The error seems pretty clear to me: the URL you're using looks like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=set_to_true_or_false
```

The error requests simply that you decide whether that "sensor" parameter should be considered `true` or `false`.